# Nvidia graphics driver problem on Ubuntu 18.04 (GPU at BusId doesn't have a supported video decoder)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-settings

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with Nvidia MX110 graphics, and I have recently had problems with installing drivers. After numerous tries, I've succeeded in installing 440 driver somehow, although I still have one warning when I run nvidia-settings in terminal.

`(nvidia-settings:16242): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 16:33:57.281: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed`

`GPU at BusId 0x1 doesn't have a supported video decoder`

```
** Message: 16:33:57.471: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 16:33:57.471: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 16:33:57.531: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|query
** Message: 16:33:57.531: PRIME: on-demand mode: "0"
** Message: 16:33:57.531: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? no
```

Graphics card and driver are recognized by system, I can switch between performance and power saving modes (my integrated graphics), but I noticed little bugs, such as couple of seconds of freeze when closing some program or switching focus to another. I wonder if this may be linked to that, because I did not have this problem before, when my driver wasn't working and when I ran it only on integrated intel graphics.

Answer (score 0):

It caused due to your chips don't have a working video decoding hardware. For now video decoding capabilities on systems may only supported by the embedded Intel iGPU.

Regards,

Comment: This is more a comment than answer.